# Proguard parseException with -dontoptimize command

Tags: android, proguard

I use proguard with optimization enabled, but I need to exclude a class `MyCarGrid` from the proguard optimization process

so I have write in my proguard config file

```
-dontoptimize MyCarGrid{*;}
```

Unfortunately proguard doesn't accept this syntax and return the following error

```
Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2013-08-30 00:03:37 - MyApp] proguard.ParseException: Unknown option 'MyCarGrid' in line 76 of file 'D:\Eclipse\MyApp\proguard-project.txt',
[2013-08-30 00:03:37 - MyApp]   included from argument number 2
[2013-08-30 00:03:37 - MyApp]   at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parse(ConfigurationParser.java:217)
[2013-08-30 00:03:37 - MyApp]   at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:476)
```

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the class, its fields, and its methods (but not the actual bytecode inside the methods) from being removed, optimized, and obfuscated:

```
-keep class mypackage.MyCarGrid { *; }
```

Comment: so the keep function is also to exclude optimization and not only obfuscation of the selected class? Thanks